# Is there a way to access the mysql database without running MAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, macos

I'm working on laravel, and I run the project using the command

```
 php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

But When I want to look at the database I quit and go to run the MAMP , to access the phpMyAdmin ?

is there any way to use mysql without having to run mamp ?

Comment: Configure them manually.

Comment: Installed Mysql,phpmyadmin separately as like Apache. For more information look at [HERE](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-9-mavericks/)

Comment: You're looking for just any frontend or _must_ it be phpmyadmin (for some reason)?  see http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: you want to start mysql on starup of your mac OS. Is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Sequel Pro. I'm assuming you're on a Mac since you use MAMP.

More info here: http://www.sequelpro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't require apache server to run.
You can use mysql cli for accessing database. 
[Link](http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/a/Installing-Mysql-On-A-Mac.htm) to install mysql

use `mysql -u {username} -p` and enter password